# Do you have to parse a string to a double every time you want to use it?

Tags: java

I am writing a program where the application has text fields to enter dollar amounts.

There are methods that need to throw exceptions for items such as dollar amounts less than zero. when doing this I have check for exceptions like this:

```
if (Double.parseDouble(str) <= 0 || Double.parseDouble(str) > 10000)
    throw new InvaildDepositAmount("Deposit Amount " + str);
else
    totalBalance += amount;
```

My question is : Do I need to  use the `Double.parseDouble(str)` every time I want to use this input, such in the `InvalidDepositAmount` class?

Comment: You can create a method wrapping that condition

Comment: Just store the value in a variable.

Comment: why don;t you just do `double value = Double.parseDouble(str);` and then just use the `value` instead of parsing the same string  over and over again ?

Comment: "why don;t you just do double value = Double.parseDouble(str); and then just use the value instead of parsing the same string over and over again ? –  Svetlin Zarev"  I will try this! Thanks!

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but you should not use doubles for dollar amounts. Use BigDecimal instead. Doubles have all sorts of rounding issues, and are more appropriate for approximations. For instance, hey can't store 1/10. See http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer is **no**.  You can parse it once and use it as a variable later.

```
double depositAmount = Double.parseDouble(str);
if (depositAmount <= 0 || depositAmount > 10000)
    throw new InvaildDepositAmount("Deposit Amount " + depositAmount);
else
    totalBalance += depositAmount;
```

This is also more efficient because, what if the call to `parseDouble` were expensive (that is, it took a long time for it to get an answer)?  Calling it once would be more efficient and easier to read in the long run.

Answer (score 5):

You can just use a variable.

```
double x = 0;    
try {    
    double x = Double.parseDouble(str);        
} catch(Exception ex) {
    throw new InvaildDepositAmount("Deposit Amount " + str)    
}
if (x <= 0 || x > 10000) {
    throw new InvaildDepositAmount("Deposit Amount " + str)
}
```

I think it makes to code readable, but I'm not sure if it makes it more efficient because the compiler or JVM could notice that and use that expression just once (and do exactly what i'm doing in the code :))

Comment: From the Java Documentation: Double.parseDouble(String s) Throws:
    NullPointerException - if the string is null
    NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable double.

Comment: This answer would be improved by some explanation alongside the code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have following cases here:
1. input field that should accept only double numbers
2. some functions which accept limited range of double numbers

Obviously you can cache entered value to avoid redundant invocation of Double.parseDouble. Also you should keep that cached value actual and update it if user changed the value in input field.

In case of exceptions related to limits in your functions you can show some popup, or update status line or whatever is suitable for your application. Or probably you want to limit input field about entered value and validate value after each change.